# Debug several projects simultaneously

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio 2012, I have a solution, which contains two projects. One is a server, second one is a client. When I hit F5, I usually want to start debugging both them at the same time. How do I do that?

I am aware that I can a) right-click on project and "debug\new instance" or b) run executable and attach to process. What I want is a setup which will launch debug simultaneously on server project when client project is F5'ed, without having to click around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio, right-click on the solution, and click "Properties"
2. Click on "Startup Project"
3. Select "Multiple startup projects"
4. In the list, change "Action" to "Start" for the projects you want to debug

Comment: yep... it's there! tyvm